# Disable creation of desktop.ini in Windows 8 (on the Desktop)

Tags: windows-8, desktop.ini

There are a few questions about the issue and they propose some solutions:

- Disable displaying of hidden files (no solution at all)
- Unchecking "Remember each folder's view settings" (which is not present in Windows 8!)
- Creating "UseDesktopIniCache" in registry - which doesn't work either

Are there any other solutions that prevents creation of this file? It's keep poping up on my Desktop and it's driving me nuts...

OK, so Windows finally decided to stop pestering me with this nonsensical file... Yay, but I still would love to know how/why...

Comment: Are you sure **Don't show hidden files** and **Hide protected OS files** are *both* [selected](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/show-hidden-files-in-windows-8/)?

Comment: I'm sure that both of this option are **NOT** selected... I want to see both system files and hidden files. Srsly, what's the point of hiding them?

Comment: added EDIT with information, that windows is no longer creating the file...

Answer (score 4):

Create a registry (*.reg) file with the following text:

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer]
"UseDesktopIniCache"=dword:00000000
```

And run it.

Comment: Right, great, now READ the OP and noticed that there is a point that I've already tried it and it DOES NOT WORK and IT WAS NOT WORKING for a long time! :[

Answer (score 0):

What is your reason for wanting to get rid of desktop.ini(s)?

If you actually dislike just one particular item in those files then there seems to be a "GPP" to do that:

Source: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f3381a83-f26a-4ac3-a18e-a342064dc5e6/ignore-localizedresourcename-in-desktopini?forum=winservergen

> Group Policy Preference - GPP Action: Delete
>
> File Path:                     %HomeShare%desktop.ini
>
> Section Name:            .ShellClassInfo
>
> Property Name:           LocalizedResourceName

Comment: They are pointless to me. Besides, I haven't been using Windows for almost 8 years now...

Answer (score -3):

Please follow the procedure given below if you are using Windows 8:

1. Open My Computer
2. Open Desktop
3. Click on **View** ( located at the top)
4. Uncheck the 'Hidden Items' box.

It should solve your problem.

Comment: First of all - there is no such option! second of all - please read again my OP and then, I dunno... try to comprehend what was written? I've explicitly said that tweaking display of hidden item is no solution...

Answer (score -3):

You should only check the *Hide protected operating system files* box instead of all the system and hidden files in the *Folder Options* menu.

That was a problem for me, too. As far as I learned from my research on this issue, these files are not supposed to be deleted, but hidden. So, I was disappointed thinking that I am supposed to hide my system and hidden files – I would hate that, too!